# Why so many ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken exceptions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I understand conceptually how the authenticity token works, but I don't understand how I seem to get so many of them!  Many of them from within the app - after a user has logged in.  What scenario would explain how a valid user could actually cause an `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`?  Sorry if this is vague, I'm just not sure where else to look.

** Note: I'm starting to wonder if these errors occur after a deploy?  Is it possible that each deploy is invalidating the previous tokens?

Comment: Please post an example of controller (and request) where you get the exception.

Comment: The requests never hit the controller since this exception is raised beforehand.  The request appears legitimate and has an authenticity token.